# Combine raster layers with same spatial extent but different data to multivariable value attribute table

Tags: qgis

Does QGIS allow to combine several raster layers having the same spatial extent, but containing data of different dates, to one single raster with an attribute table of several columns (as with the COMBINE tool of the Spatial Analyst in ArcMap)?

Comment: You can merge rasters under Raster-->various (I do not know the english term) --> Merge.